# Calculating average from 2 database table columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to calculate an average based on values from 2 table columns in `MySQL`.

Lets say I have this table structure:

```
id | user_id | first_score | last_score
1  | 1       |  10         | 60
2  | 1       |  70         | 10
3  | 1       |  100        | NULL
```

What I am trying to achieve  here, is calculating the AVG of the highest value (i.e. 60, 70, 100).  But seeing as they are in different colums, not sure how to go about it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You solve this with the GREATEST function. Unfortunately it results in NULL when one or both values are NULL. So:

```
select avg( greatest( coalesce(first_score,last_score) , coalesce(last_score,first_score) ) )
from mytable;
```

Comment: That was quick and worked superbly..  Didnt even know of the GREATEST function in MySQL.

Comment: You could also phrase this as:  `select avg(coalesce(greatest(first_score, last_score), first_score, last_score))`

Comment: Yeah, GREATEST is great, but would even be greater if it treated NULLS like MIN does ;-) Imagine how clumsy it gets when dealing with three, four or more values.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: Yes, this saves one function call. But whatever technique one uses to defend against GREATEST's NULL awareness, it looks ugly anyway :-)

Answer (score 6):

```
select avg(GREATEST(first_score , last_score))
from the_table
```

Comment: The greatest will take NULL when comparing to any number.

Answer (score 1):

The query should be:

```
SELECT AVG(GREATEST(IFNULL(first_score,0), IFNULL(last_score,0))) AVERAGE FROM TABLE1;
```

The greatest will take NULL when comparing to any number.

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/04b31/2/0)